# Combinatorial Challenge, alternative solution process.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Problem:**

"During an election campaign $n$ different kinds of promises are made by the various political parties, $n>0$. No two parties have exactly the same set of promises. While several parties may make the same promise, every pair of parties have at least one promise in common.

Prove that there can be as many as $2^{n-1}$ parties, but no more."

Aside from the consideration of treating each sets of promises made by each party as a sequence of promises, and relating that to the fact that there can be $2^{n}$ unique sets of promises. (hint: binary)

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much doubt that you can avoid considering subsets of the set of promises, but there's no need for sequences.

To show that $2^{n-1}$ parties are possible, fix one promise that they all make, and let each party make a different subset of the remaining $n-1$ promises. To show that this is the maximum possible number of parties, observe that the set of $n$ promises has $2^n$ subsets, so any family of more than $2^{n-1}$ subsets must contain two complementary subsets.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i thought of too! Sorry i used sequences in the wrong context.